# Find and Replace with Nginx Reverse Proxy setup

Tags: search, nginx, replace

I have a reverse proxy setup with nginx on centos 6. I am looking to take one of my pages and display different phone numbers based on what advertisement is clicked on.

I was trying to use the http_sub_module though I don't really have a clear understanding of how to find replace with it.

Example

http://mysite.com has (111) 123-4567

I would like to have the reverse proxy do a search for above number and replace with (222) 765-321

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not ideal, as really the source should be rewritten, but you can use `sub_filter` to rewrite the content of responses for proxied requests. With your example this would be:

```
location /something {
    ...

    sub_filter '(111) 123-4567' '(222) 765-321';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

The default behaviour of this is to replace once (which I have disabled in the example) and to only apply the changes to html pages (this is based on the mime type of the response). This is suitable for using in a reverse proxy as it can replace the `Location` header with the default options, and links when you disable the `sub_filter_once` option.

While this module is not available unless explicitly configured at compile time, it is my experience that any package manager installed nginx has this option enabled.

You can read more about this [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html).